# Set value in Arraylist nested Java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, netbeans

i wanna set the value in the follow code, i am using arraylist how Data structure, i need change the int value, its the last value. i am using in other class a setter for change this value but i am try change this with

doc.set(int index,E element) but dont work.

ArrayList doc = new ArrayList();

```
    doc.add(new Docentes1("carlos","ortega","Cra 1 #e-22","M","3432323",32));
    doc.add(new Docentes1("juan","calvo","Cra 22 #r-22","M","342566323",28));
    doc.add(new Docentes1("hermes","tango","Cra 77 #55-45","M","3432323",20));
    doc.add(new Docentes1("julia","bueno","Cra 5 #323-32","F","3432323",40));
```

I know  this method only work for array with a unique value, Can you help me, i need change the last value of specific element because i need iterate de diferents elements inside the array.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
doc.stream().forEach(u -> u.setProperty("value"));
```

where setProperty() is the setter method for the attribute you need to set.